# Select or Join tatement for BIRT Report using SQL

Tags: sql, select, left-join, reporting, birt

I am just getting back into writing SQL Select Statements and I am have an issue. I have an existing report that works perfectly. However, I was asked to add some fields in the result set. The filed is in a table with a foreign key relationship. I am trying to add it to the query and I am failing. I can write the select statement separately and it returns the right results. I just don't know how to add it to the existing statement. I have tried left joins, adding it to the select and where but the result set is wrong. I would like to add the following to return the info if available to the result set in a new column but not prevent other data if null.

I would like to add:
    select sc.FACILITY_ID, ce.schd_id
    from PA_SCHED sc, PA_CPNT_EVTHST ce
    where sc.SCHD_ID = ce.schd_id

To the following:

```
select s.stud_id as studID, s.lname as lastName, s.fname as firstName, s.mi
as middleName,
   s.EMP_STAT_ID ,s.EMP_TYP_ID ,s.JL_ID ,s.JP_ID ,s.TARGET_JP_ID ,
   s.JOB_TITLE ,s.DMN_ID ,s.ORG_ID ,s.REGION_ID, s.CO_ID , DECODE
  (s.NOTACTIVE,'Y','N','N','Y') as active ,
   s.ADDR ,s.CITY ,s.STATE ,s.POSTAL ,s.CNTRY, s.SUPER , s.COACH_STUD_ID ,
   s.HIRE_DTE,s.TERM_DTE ,s.EMAIL_ADDR, s.RESUME_LOCN ,s.COMMENTS , 
   s.SHIPPING_NAME ,
   s.SHIPPING_CONTACT_NAME,  
   s.SHIPPING_ADDR ,s.SHIPPING_ADDR1 ,s.SHIPPING_CITY ,
   s.SHIPPING_STATE,
   s.SHIPPING_POSTAL ,s.SHIPPING_CNTRY ,s.SHIPPING_PHON_NUM,
   s.SHIPPING_FAX_NUM, 
   s.SHIPPING_EMAIL_ADDR ,s.STUD_PSWD ,s.PIN ,s.PIN_DATE,
   s.ENCRYPTED , s.HAS_ACCESS ,s.BILLING_NAME , s.BILLING_CONTACT_NAME ,
   s.BILLING_ADDR ,s.BILLING_ADDR1 ,s.BILLING_CITY ,s.BILLING_STATE ,
   s.BILLING_POSTAL,
   s.BILLING_CNTRY , 
   s.BILLING_PHON_NUM ,s.BILLING_FAX_NUM ,s.BILLING_EMAIL_ADDR ,
   s.SELF_REGISTRATION ,s.SELF_REGISTRATION_DATE, s.ACCESS_TO_ORG_FIN_ACT ,
   s.NOTIFY_DEV_PLAN_ITEM_ADD , s.NOTIFY_DEV_PLAN_ITEM_MOD ,
   s.NOTIFY_DEV_PLAN_ITEM_REMOVE ,
   s.NOTIFY_WHEN_SUB_ITEM_COMPLETE ,s.NOTIFY_WHEN_SUB_ITEM_FAILURE ,
   s.LOCKED ,s.PASSWORD_EXP_DATE,s.SECURITY_QUESTION ,
   s.SECURITY_ANSWER ,s.ROLE_ID ,s.IMAGE_ID ,s.GENDER ,s.PAST_SERVICE, 
   s.LST_UNLOCK_TSTMP,
   s.LST_UPD_USR, s.LST_UPD_TSTMP,s.MANAGE_SUB_SP, s.MANAGE_OWN_SP,

   e.cpnt_typ_id as cpntTypeID, e.cpnt_id as cpntID, e.rev_dte as revDate, 
   e.rev_num as revNum,
   e.schd_id as schedID, cp.cpnt_title as cpntDesc, e.grade,
   e.compl_dte as complDate, e.cmpl_stat_id as complStatID,
   cs.cmpl_stat_desc as complStatDesc, nvl(e.total_hrs, 0) as totalHrs,
   nvl(e.credit_hrs, 0) as creditHrs, nvl(e.contact_hrs, 0) as contactHrs,
   nvl(e.cpe_hrs, 0) as cpeHrs, nvl(oi.price, 0) as tuition,
   e.inst_name as instName, e.comments as eventComments, e.es_user_name as 
   esUserName,
   e.lst_upd_tstmp as lstTmsp,
   e.esig_meaning_code_id || '  ' ||  e.esig_meaning_code_desc as 
   esigMeaningCode,
   e.currency_code as currencyCode, cur.symbol as currencySymbol, 
   cur.description,
   cur.active, cur.is_default, cur.label_id
   ,s.jl_id
   ,s.job_title
   ,s.super
   ,s.hire_dte
   ,s.term_dte
   ,eeno.user_value
   ,co.user_value
```

from pa_student s, PA_CPNT_EVTHST e, PA_CMPL_STAT cs,
        pa_fin_order_item oi, pa_currency cur, pa_cpnt cp,

```
   (SELECT s.stud_id, f.user_value
FROM PA_STUD_USER f, pa_student s
WHERE s.stud_id = f.stud_id (+)
AND f.col_num (+) = '10') eeno
,(SELECT s.stud_id, f.user_value
FROM PA_STUD_USER f, pa_student s
WHERE s.stud_id = f.stud_id (+)
AND f.col_num (+) = '40') co

where e.stud_id = s.stud_id
  and e.cmpl_stat_id = cs.cmpl_stat_id
  and e.currency_code = cur.currency_code(+)
  and e.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id(+)
  and cp.cpnt_typ_id(+) = e.cpnt_typ_id
  and cp.cpnt_id(+) = e.cpnt_id
  and cp.rev_dte(+) = e.rev_dte
  and s.stud_id = eeno.stud_id(+) 
  AND s.stud_id = co.stud_id(+)




 /**  and trunc(e.compl_dte) >= [FromDate] 
   and not trunc(e.compl_dte) > [ToDate]  
   and s.stud_id in [UserSearch]
   and e.cpnt_typ_id in [ItemTypeSearch]
   and [security:pa_student s] */
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Added this in FROM ...

```
  (select sc.FACILITY_ID, ce.schd_id from PA_SCHED sc 
  where sc.SCHD_ID (+) = e.schd_id
  ) sc
```

and   appended `sc.FACILITY_ID` in the main `SELECT` ...

See if this works ...

```
SELECT s.stud_id AS studID,
  s.lname        AS lastName,
  s.fname        AS firstName,
  s.mi           AS middleName,
  s.EMP_STAT_ID ,
  s.EMP_TYP_ID ,
  s.JL_ID ,
  s.JP_ID ,
  s.TARGET_JP_ID ,
  s.JOB_TITLE ,
  s.DMN_ID ,
  s.ORG_ID ,
  s.REGION_ID,
  s.CO_ID ,
  DECODE (s.NOTACTIVE,'Y','N','N','Y') AS active ,
  s.ADDR ,
  s.CITY ,
  s.STATE ,
  s.POSTAL ,
  s.CNTRY,
  s.SUPER ,
  s.COACH_STUD_ID ,
  s.HIRE_DTE,
  s.TERM_DTE ,
  s.EMAIL_ADDR,
  s.RESUME_LOCN ,
  s.COMMENTS ,
  s.SHIPPING_NAME ,
  s.SHIPPING_CONTACT_NAME,
  s.SHIPPING_ADDR ,
  s.SHIPPING_ADDR1 ,
  s.SHIPPING_CITY ,
  s.SHIPPING_STATE,
  s.SHIPPING_POSTAL ,
  s.SHIPPING_CNTRY ,
  s.SHIPPING_PHON_NUM,
  s.SHIPPING_FAX_NUM,
  s.SHIPPING_EMAIL_ADDR ,
  s.STUD_PSWD ,
  s.PIN ,
  s.PIN_DATE,
  s.ENCRYPTED ,
  s.HAS_ACCESS ,
  s.BILLING_NAME ,
  s.BILLING_CONTACT_NAME ,
  s.BILLING_ADDR ,
  s.BILLING_ADDR1 ,
  s.BILLING_CITY ,
  s.BILLING_STATE ,
  s.BILLING_POSTAL,
  s.BILLING_CNTRY ,
  s.BILLING_PHON_NUM ,
  s.BILLING_FAX_NUM ,
  s.BILLING_EMAIL_ADDR ,
  s.SELF_REGISTRATION ,
  s.SELF_REGISTRATION_DATE,
  s.ACCESS_TO_ORG_FIN_ACT ,
  s.NOTIFY_DEV_PLAN_ITEM_ADD ,
  s.NOTIFY_DEV_PLAN_ITEM_MOD ,
  s.NOTIFY_DEV_PLAN_ITEM_REMOVE ,
  s.NOTIFY_WHEN_SUB_ITEM_COMPLETE ,
  s.NOTIFY_WHEN_SUB_ITEM_FAILURE ,
  s.LOCKED ,
  s.PASSWORD_EXP_DATE,
  s.SECURITY_QUESTION ,
  s.SECURITY_ANSWER ,
  s.ROLE_ID ,
  s.IMAGE_ID ,
  s.GENDER ,
  s.PAST_SERVICE,
  s.LST_UNLOCK_TSTMP,
  s.LST_UPD_USR,
  s.LST_UPD_TSTMP,
  s.MANAGE_SUB_SP,
  s.MANAGE_OWN_SP,
  e.cpnt_typ_id AS cpntTypeID,
  e.cpnt_id     AS cpntID,
  e.rev_dte     AS revDate,
  e.rev_num     AS revNum,
  e.schd_id     AS schedID,
  cp.cpnt_title AS cpntDesc,
  e.grade,
  e.compl_dte           AS complDate,
  e.cmpl_stat_id        AS complStatID,
  cs.cmpl_stat_desc     AS complStatDesc,
  NVL(e.total_hrs, 0)   AS totalHrs,
  NVL(e.credit_hrs, 0)  AS creditHrs,
  NVL(e.contact_hrs, 0) AS contactHrs,
  NVL(e.cpe_hrs, 0)     AS cpeHrs,
  NVL(oi.price, 0)      AS tuition,
  e.inst_name           AS instName,
  e.comments            AS eventComments,
  e.es_user_name        AS esUserName,
  e.lst_upd_tstmp       AS lstTmsp,
  e.esig_meaning_code_id
  || '  '
  || e.esig_meaning_code_desc AS esigMeaningCode,
  e.currency_code             AS currencyCode,
  cur.symbol                  AS currencySymbol,
  cur.description,
  cur.active,
  cur.is_default,
  cur.label_id ,
  s.jl_id ,
  s.job_title ,
  s.super ,
  s.hire_dte ,
  s.term_dte ,
  eeno.user_value ,
  co.user_value,
  e.schd_id,
  sc.FACILITY_ID
FROM pa_student s,
  PA_CPNT_EVTHST e,
  PA_CMPL_STAT cs,
  pa_fin_order_item oi,
  pa_currency cur,
  pa_cpnt cp,
  (SELECT s.stud_id,
    f.user_value
  FROM PA_STUD_USER f,
    pa_student s
  WHERE s.stud_id   = f.stud_id (+)
  AND f.col_num (+) = '10'
  ) eeno ,
  (SELECT s.stud_id,
    f.user_value
  FROM PA_STUD_USER f,
    pa_student s
  WHERE s.stud_id   = f.stud_id (+)
  AND f.col_num (+) = '40'
  ) co ,
  (select sc.FACILITY_ID, ce.schd_id from PA_SCHED sc 
  where sc.SCHD_ID (+) = e.schd_id
  ) sc
WHERE e.stud_id       = s.stud_id
AND e.cmpl_stat_id    = cs.cmpl_stat_id
AND e.currency_code   = cur.currency_code(+)
AND e.order_item_id   = oi.order_item_id(+)
AND cp.cpnt_typ_id(+) = e.cpnt_typ_id
AND cp.cpnt_id(+)     = e.cpnt_id
AND cp.rev_dte(+)     = e.rev_dte
AND s.stud_id         = eeno.stud_id(+)
AND s.stud_id         = co.stud_id(+);
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try.